# spark and livy: state running to dead, how to troubleshoot

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, livy

I am running a spark jon in an EMR cluster using livy

```
response= requests.post("http://"+host + ':8998/batches', data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

and now trying to poll to see the spark job is done

in side a while loop check batch-response

batch_id = response.json()['id']
session_url = "http://" + livy_endpoint + ":8998/batches/{}".format(batch_id)
batch_response = requests.get(session_url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

I see changing from state="running to state = "dead"

what does mean, how to debug the issue